# git pull origin branch-name not pulling all the commits " already up to date "

Tags: git, bitbucket

Trying to pull updated work in branch but missing some recent commits into it.

It is strange that it is missing just today's commits.

Tried

```
git pull origin branch-name
```

Getting message "Already up to date."
Also Tried

```
git fetch --all 
git reset --hard origin/branch-name
```

It there any which is missing

Remember i was able to pull updated code before 3 or 4 days

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After executing git pull origin it will give you Already up to date.
Then use git checkout branch 
and  run git status you will see you file .